# How can I protect some fields if a user has a concret role? Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I need help, I have been trying to hide/protect some fields of my employee form, I want to protect the fields that are below the second header, I want only if the admin has the permission to assign employee to company can I see it, but the The problem comes if the user modifies the html creating fields that in theory he could not modify, so for this I need to validate it in the backend, I have thought about using a middleware to detect if the request has protected fields but I don't know if that is the way to do it , someone could help me?

here's my form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Crear empleado</title>
</head>

<body>
<form action="{{ route('employee.store') }}" method="post">
    @csrf

    <H1>Datos personales del empleado</H1>
    <label for="name">Nombre</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Ruben" id="">
    <label for="name">Apellido Paterno</label>
    <input type="text" name="fathers_last_name" placeholder="Garcia" id="">
    <label for="name">Apellido Materno</label>
    <input type="text" name="mothers_last_name" placeholder="Garcia" id="">
    <label for="name">Correo</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Ruben@example.com" id="">
    <label for="name">Curp</label>
    <input type="text" name="curp" placeholder="KUHP800903MWUIF" id="">
    <label for="name">RFC</label>
    <input type="text" name="rfc" placeholder="KUHP800903MWUIF" id="">
    <label for="name">Imss</label>
    <input type="text" name="imss" placeholder="KUHP800903MWUIF" id="">
    <label for="name">Edad</label>
    <input type="text" name="age" placeholder="50" id="">
    <label for="name">Telefonos</label>
    <input type="tel" name="telefono" placeholder="50" id="">
    <label for="name">Fecha nacimiento</label>
    <input type="date" name="birth_date" id="">

    <label for="name">Genero</label>
    <label for="name">Estado Civil</label>
    <select name="gender_id" id="">
        @foreach ($martialStatuses as $martialStatus)
        <option value="{{$martialStatus->id}}">{{ $martialStatus->name }}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
    <select name="gender_id" id="">
        @foreach ($genders as $gender)
        <option value="{{$gender->id}}">{{ $gender->name }}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>

    @livewire('adress')

    <label for="street">Calle</label>
    <input type="text" name="street" id="">
    @error('street')
    {{ $message }}
    @enderror
    <label for="interior_number">Numero Interior</label>
    <input type="number" name="interior_number" id="">
    @error('interior_number')
    {{ $message }}
    @enderror
    <label for="exterior_number">Numero Exterior</label>
    <input type="number" name="exterior_number" id="">
    @error('exterior_number')
    {{ $message }}
    @enderror
    <label for="zip_code">Codigo Postal</label>
    <input type="number" name="zip_code" id="">
    @error('zip_code')
    {{ $message }}
    @enderror
    <br>

    <label for="active">Puede Ingresa a la aplicacion</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="active" id="active">

    <!-- only for administrator who has the permission -->

    @can('assing.employee')
    <h1>Datos del empleado</h1>
    <label for="">Empresa asignada</label>
    <select name="company_id" id="">
        @foreach ($companies as $company)
        <option value="{{$company->id}}">{{ $company->name }}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
    <label for="">Equipo</label>
    <select name="team_id" id="">
        @foreach ($teams as $team)
        <option value="{{$team->id}}">{{ $team->name }}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
    <label for="">Codigo de empleado</label>
    <input type="text" name="employe_code">
    <label for="">Fecha de ingreso</label>
    <input type="date" name="start_date">
    <br>
    @endcan
    <input type="submit" value="Crear">
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: In frontend your work it's ok. About backend, you can add a middleware or use Laravel Policies for to check each request you are processing. Policies are maked for do that, middleware is good for this and for much more.

I usually filter the input array only passing the fields that are allowed, but now that I think about it, it would be useful to check if there are any disallowed fields in the request and if so, notify the administrator with a complete report. https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/requests#retrieving-a-portion-of-the-input-data

Comment: Not trusting user supplied data is considered standard practice. Laravel has [validation](https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/validation) which you should always do when accepting user supplied data before you use it. You should also keep track of data that is coming from a user to make sure you never use it elsewhere (e.g. in SQL queries or showing them in HTML pages) without doing some sort of processing on them